# yii javascript script inline

Tags: php, cakephp, yii

i have a very long javascript and i need to use YII CHtml function inside it, however, the quote string making the code very messy.

for example,

```
$script = "$('#car_brand').click(function(e), {
   //codes
   var car_name = /"bmw/";
});";
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('car-js', $script); ?>
```

the above problem just showing an example of short version. Is there anything equailvent to CakePHP's scriptBlock function?

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1604/scriptBlock

Thanks

Comment: in my opinion, writing javascript in pure php is messy regardless. The best bet is to set a header for a js file and write the code there and use php when needed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> $script = <<< EOD
>
> ```
> /* here you write your javascript normally in multiple lines */
> ```
>
> EOD;
>
> Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('someId', $script);

You can write like this.

Comment: This is how I usually handle this situation. It is called heredoc notation and you can view the details of how it works here. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily the correct way, but it's what I always do because the whole Yii script thing with the quotes drives me crazy.

In my layout I load jQuery (and usually jQueryUI if I'm going to use it) like so:

```
<?php cs()->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
<?php cs()->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui'); ?>
```

I then just use script in normal script tags as I would do if I wasn't using Yii. By loading jQuery with registerCoreScript instead of just linking to jQuery in the "normal" way, it prevents issues with the script Yii uses for stuff like CGridView

Like I said, not the most correct way, but I find it to be the best solution for me because I use loads of javascript